# Нужна ли запятая после "даже так"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

> Но даже так(,) ты для меня самый лучший.

Нужна ли здесь запятая? Или тире, чтобы подчеркнуть мысль (подытог)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом случае или ничего не ставится, или ставится интонационное тире (при подчеркивании итога темы):

(1) ***Но даже так ты для меня самый лучший.***

(2) ***Но даже так ― ты для меня самый лучший.***

Пример:

*Но даже так ― какой это большой настоящий праздник.* [О. Н. Ковалёва. Дневник (1984)]